# Change or reset prepackaged database in DBFlow

Tags: android, sqlite, dbflow

I am a beginner in android programming, I created an android app which uses an exist DB with DBFlow. At first time I inserted a temp data to database so I can test the app. When I finished building the app I inserted real data and copied the new database -which is similar to the old one except for the real data- to assets folder but I did not find the new data.

How can I reset the database or change the data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After changing database you must remove previous version of app from your device and then install the app again. This should solve your problem.